# flutter_image_picker creates a file named flutter_image_picker_file_paths 2.xml

Tags: android, flutter, imagepicker

At some point of time this file gets created which causes Android build to fail. The file content is the same as flutter_image_picker_file_paths.xml content, and you can find it in a folder, delete it, run flutter clean and build app again without a problem. But after some time it gets created again and it is really irritating. Does anyone know how and when it is created, and if there is a way to stop it from creating?
I'm using image_picker: ^0.8.3+2